# Mockito mocks refers to all object of the mocked class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm testing my code with Mockito and I have used:

```
RequestWrapper requestWrapper = mock(RequestWrapper.class);
```

I thought it mocks the **requestWrapper instance** of RequestWrapper.class.

Instead, when in the code of the ***system under test*** I debug this:

```
RequestWrapper a = new RequestWrapper(request);
RequestWrapper b = new RequestWrapper(request);
RequestWrapper c = new RequestWrapper(request);
```

I figure out that **a, b, c** instances of RequestWrapper are all mocked.
So it seems that the instance name of the Mocked class (not mocked Object then as I figured out!) has no importance at all.

So, my questions are:

- what sense has mocking an instance of a class (defining a specific instance name) if when you use *Mockito.mock()* you get all instances of the same class mocked equally?
- And the other one is, if I want to define different behaviours of my mocked instances, do I have to declare in the test the correct names of the instances in order to define a different behaviour with *when().then()*?

### EDIT: Update

Sorry I got wrong. Only the instance explicitly mocked become a mock. The others are object of the real classes. I got wrong because of all the other mocked dependencies in the real class too.

So it's not true that if I mock an instance of a class, all the other instances of that class are instantiated as mocks. They are object of the real class.

Thank you for your useful answers, I apologize for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I got wrong. Only the instance explicitly mocked become a mock. The others are object of the real classes. I got wrong because of all the other mocked dependencies in the real class too.

So it's not true that if I mock an instance of a class, all the other instances of that class are instantiated as mocks. They are object of the real class.

Thank you for your useful answers, I apologize for the error.

Answer (score 4):

Your assumptions on mocks are incorrect.

When your code under test instantiates new objects (`new RequestWrapper()`) mocks created using `Mockito.mock()` **are not used** (unless you are mocking constructors using e.g. Powermock, but that is another story).

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers are outlining: you got mocking wrong.

The point is: you do **not** want to mock "all" instances of a class. To the contrary: you **only** create mock objects when you have to. A mock is a *mean* to make it easier (or possible!) to test a specific piece of code. In other words: the mock allows you to **control** something that is used within that piece of code.

You are therefore **only** interested in controlling that **one specific** object that your "code under test" will be using.

You absolutely do **not** want to control each and any instance of class X when you use `mock(X.class)` or `@Mock X x` somewhere in your unit test!

And yes, when you have

```
X mock1 = mock(X.class);
X mock2 = mock(X.class);
```

then you need separate `when().then()` or `verify()` specifications for *both* of those objects (in case the default behaviours that mockito provides aren't sufficient). And that is again a consequence of what I wrote above: it should be absolutely clear to you "which" mock "goes where".

Answer (score 1):

Each of the separate RequestWrapper objects that are used in the method under test have to be created independently using `Mockito.mock()` or using the `@Mock` annotation.

Then each of them would have to be set-up independently using `when().then()` syntax.

If you are using many mocks of the same class in one test method, then the `mock(Class<T> classToMock, String name)` would be helpfull in terms of debugging or assertion failure logging.